# Missing Temporary Folder in WordPress (PHP 5.6) on IIS, Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I am helping out with a WordPress site which is hosted on IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2, running PHP 5.6
(don't ask - and please don't snark - this is a website for my local church)

For some reason I keep getting "Missing Temporary Folder" everytime someone tries to upload any media files.

I have tried creating a "temp" folder in the "wp-content" folder.
I have also reset all permissions on the ENTIRE wp-content folder, removing any "read-only" locks and granting all users "full control" (yes - I'm getting this desperate to just get the dang thing working at this point!)

In the wp-config.php I've specified my temp directory.
(this used to be a relative path, but I've switched to an absolute path, just to rule out the virtual directory in IIS confusing things)

`define('WP_TEMP_DIR', 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wp_church\wp-content\temp');`

In my PHP.ini (in the installation folder for PHP) I defined:

`upload_tmp_dir = C:\wpupload`

I created that folder, and again gave all users full control.

I have since rebooted the server and run IISRESET numerous times.

But every time I try uploading a media file I still get the error message:

`Missing Temporary Folder`

Can anyone help???
Please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry about this.

it would appear that "upload_tmp_dir" is declared TWICE in the php.ini file.

I found another one right at the very bottom. I changed that .. all fixed!!

Comment: Please mark the answer so that it can help others with similar problems.